# mysqli select query works in FF, not in Chrome, IE or Edge

Tags: php, mysqli

Can anyone see why this SQL query works in Firefox but not in Chrome or Edge.
In Chrome and Edge I get the following error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/mydomain/public_html/apps/2018/index.php on line 154

```
$query_ArrayLookup = "SELECT SeqID FROM ".$SequenceNo_default." WHERE SeqActive = 0";
$ArrayLookup = mysqli_query($link,$query_ArrayLookup);
$ArrayLookupCount = $ArrayLookup->num_rows;

while ($row_ArrayLookup = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ArrayLookup)){ // Line 154
    $ActiveSeq[] = $row_ArrayLookup['SeqID'];
}
```

Comment: @Alaa Ali  Hi, the $SequenceNo_default is a variable containing the tabel name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_fetch\_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind\_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$query_ArrayLookup = "SELECT SeqID FROM `{$SequenceNo_default}` WHERE SeqActive = 0";
$ArrayLookup = mysqli_query($link,$query_ArrayLookup);
$ArrayLookupCount = $ArrayLookup->num_rows;

while ($row_ArrayLookup = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ArrayLookup)){ 
    $ActiveSeq[] = $row_ArrayLookup['SeqID'];
}
```

It's working fine on edge and google chrome, IE.